# How to launch Android Telegram

Tags: android, telegram

I'm developing source Telegram to run the version available in the Gate have a problem I think in relation to the source code is Native. In general, to run its native what should be done at the source telegram?

In this photo problem occurred when running the confusing because according to project packages all is good.

[image: error picture]

> Error:error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
>       make: *** [C:/dev/workspace/android/MygramNew/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtmessages.24.so]
>   Error 1
>       :TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildArmv7Debug FAILED
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildArmv7Debug'.
>
> > Build command failed.
> >         Error while executing 'C:\dev\sdk\android-ndk\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
> >     APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\dev\workspace\android\MygramNew\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
> >     NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\dev\workspace\android\MygramNew\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk
> >     APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDEBUG=1
> >     APP_PLATFORM=android-14
> >     NDK_OUT=C:/dev/workspace/android/MygramNew/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj
> >     NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\dev\workspace\android\MygramNew\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\debug\lib
> >     NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14
> >     C:/dev/workspace/android/MygramNew/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtmessages.24.so}
> >         [armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libtmessages.24.so
> >         arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
> >         make: *** [C:/dev/workspace/android/MygramNew/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtmessages.24.so]
> >     Error 1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... you have to install the NDK with SDK android manager, then reopen your project to synchronize with gradle... sorry for my english =D

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. Maybe "APP_PLATFORM=android-14" version is too low.I try to replace "android-14" with android-17(Maybe 16 is OK.)..It worked.